# Viewing source code of a function

Tags: r

I'm trying to look at how R calculates the p-values for the chi-square test. How do I view the source code?

Comment: https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-see-source-code-of-a-functionmethod-in-r/

Comment: Welcome to cross-validated. Usually coding specific questions are better posted on Stackoverflow not here. This forum is more about the statistics and modeling part.

Comment: My answer deals with how find the P-value of a chi-squared test. If you have a specific example not covered there, then you can ask a _statistical_ question about that example.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer about how to view and interpret source code.

But it seems to me that you don't need to look into the source code
in order to see how the P-value from `chisq.test` in R is computed.
The method seems transparent from observable output.

For example: The matrix `DTA` is a contingency table in which
each of the two categorical variables has three levels. Counts
are consistent with independence of the two categorical variables at the 5% level
because the P-value exceeds 0.05.

```
DTA = matrix(c(20, 30, 40,
               11, 17, 21,
               31, 32, 29), byrow=T, nrow=3)

chisq.test(DTA)

        Pearson's Chi-squared test

data:  DTA
X-squared = 4.9028, df = 4, p-value = 0.2974
```

Under the null hypothesis of independence, the the statistic
is approximately distributed as $\mathsf{Chisq}(\nu = (3-1)(3-1 = 4).$

For a compact display and to avoid giving more places of accuracy
that are ordinarily of use, R rounds the observed value of the chi-squared
statistic and the P-value.

In order to display a few more places of accuracy, we can use `$`-notation:

```
q = chisq.test(DTA)$stat;  q
X-squared 
 4.902782 
pv = chisq.test(DTA)$p.val;  pv
[1] 0.2974189
```

The P-value is the probability under the null distribution to the right of
the observed value of the test statistic:

```
1 - pchisq(as.numeric(q), 4)
[1] 0.2974189
```

*Notes:* (1) If the rounded value of the chi-squared statistic is used, then the
P-value from `pchisq` may differ from the P-value in the output, but only
within rounding error. (2) In the last R expression, `as.numeric` strips
an unnecessary label from the test statistic.